# Is there a way to make the reflection probes to work smooth without making the game lag?

Tags: unity

In the Hierarchy I have 6 Reflection Probes and the only different between each one is the position and the box size.

[image: Reflection Probes]

The problem is when i'm running the game after few seconds it's loading the reflection probes and that make the game to freeze for 1-2 seconds then the lights are changing and then the game continue regular.

Is there a way to avoid this 1-2 seconds freeze ?

Comment: I changed all the Reflection Probes to be Baked instead Realtime and then changed the Intensity on all of them to be 3. Is that a good solution ?

Comment: Yes. That will be a good solution. Some more tips in the docs https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RefProbePerformance.html